# Finding The Last Column With Filled with Data in a Range

Tags: vba, excel

I know we can get the last row with data with following code:

> LastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

But I am having trouble on getting the last Column with data. Here is what i tried bu as you can see from the image it didn't go through

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
With ws 
 Header = 5
 LastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 LastCol = .Range(5 & .ColumnCount).End(xlLeft).Column
    With .Range("A" & Header & LastCol & LastRow)
         .Interior.ColorIndex = 16
    End With
End With
```

[image]

Can you please let me know hoe I can fix this? thanks

Comment: Use `Cells` instead of `Range`.

Comment: Use `Columns.Count` instead of Column.Count

Comment: Hi Tony, Thanks for comment I fix the mistake you said but still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this as i've commented:

```
Lastcol = .Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

i'm not sure if its `xlLeft` or `xlToLeft`. Try it yourself.

Use this to color the entire range:

```
With .Range(Cells(1,5),Cells(Lastrow,Lastcol)
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 16
End With
```

this colors `A5` to your last column and row.

Comment: Thanks L42, but seems there is still something missing!  I am not getting any errors but after running the code nothing change!

Comment: What row do you  want to get the last column and what do you want your code to accomplish?  You want to change color of what range?

Comment: I was thinking to change the color of wole used range!

Comment: I mean already used something like this With .Range("A" & Header & ":C" & LastRow) .Interior.ColorIndex = 16  End With

Comment: Great , thanks it works now, what a big difference! I still do not know why you chosed Cells(1,5) why not Cells(1,1)? was there any reason?